# How to copy data to identical Postgres table with foreign key using Delphi?

Tags: database, postgresql, delphi, foreign-keys, data-transfer

I am trying to copy data from table `Orders` to table `Order_History`. Both tables have a foreign key to `Details` and `Detail_History`.

We have an `Ordernumber` column in both orders tables and a corresponding `Link_Ordernumber` column in both details tables.

I tried this code:

```
tblorderhist.Insert;
tblorderhist.CopyFields(DataModule1.tblorders);
tblorderhist.Post;
tbldetailHist.Insert;
tbldetailHist.CopyFields(DataModule1.tblline);
tbldetailHist.Post;
```

and on the line

```
tblorderhist.CopyFields(DataModule1.tblorders);
```

Delphi throws the error

> Project Prjdoors.exe raised exception class EDatabaseError with
> message 'Field 'orderno' cannot be modified'.

Comment: In most such systems orders must exist before you can add order lines. You are trying to add order lines first.

Comment: @Brian sorry for the late response. When I copied the orders first, I got the error "Project Prjdoors.exe raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'Field 'ordernumber' cannot be modified'."

Comment: Or maybe I asked the wrong question. Should I edit it with the 'cannot be modified' error?